# How do I encode an image in H.263 and send it in real time using udp

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am building a sip softphone in C#, I am through with the audio aspect, but I want to add video call capability to it, I can successfully get image from the webcamera on the system, but the problem now is I want to compress the image using h.263 codec algorithm before sending it over udp in realtime, all the codes I have been seeing on h.263 is in c++, and I am not a C++ person, please how can I implement this in C#, I mean get the video from the webcamera, encode in h263 and send it over wire in realtime, any suggestion will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do real-time streaming over UDP with both audio and video stream you can use the DirectShow API (if you're targeting Windows computers). Official documentation available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454(v=vs.85).aspx

You will find a .NET wrapper for DirectShow here: http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/ and also some samples.
You will also find more samples on codeproject.com, most of them use this wrapper: http://www.codeproject.com/kb/audio-video/#DirectShow

Using DirectShow you will be able to capture both the webcam and the microphone in realtime, encode them using the appropriate encoder filter (for instance, a h263 encoder for the video stream) and then send the encoded frames over the network using a RTSP writer filter.

I'm not an expert on DirectShow, but this could be a good starting point. I know this solution works because I've implemented it few months ago.

You need to know that DirectShow is beeing deprecated since Windows Vista, and is beeing replaced by the new API: Windows Media Foundation. If you're targeting Windows Vista or Windows 7 only, it may be a better choice to use the new API. See the MSDN documentation for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694197(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks so much, I will look into it, my target audience will include windows xp as well so, I will try out the Directshownet, once again thanks for your time