# Video/Audio Codec for Silverlight video conference

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, silverlight

I am currently developing a video conference web based application. My project is based upon the following example : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65190/Your-First-Step-to-the-Silverlight-Voice-Video-Cha ..I am currently experiencing a 'lag' in the video conference per se..

First of all i, what could be the cause of such lag? Could it be due to codec reasons? if not what could be the other possibilities?

As regards to the codec, the current project, takes a frame (i.e. JPG) encodes it and sends it.. What other codec are recommended for encoding a JPG frame and decoding it on the receiving end?

Thanks, Any kind of help is highly appreciated..

Comment: There are some open source projects such as ffd http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffdshow/ . But I'm not sure they are silverlight compaitable. As you know you can just reference sl dlls to sl projects. But I liked you idea! You may view this also http://www.atoker.com/blog/2010/02/04/html5-theora-video-codec-for-silverlight/

Comment: @DavidGurbuz.. first of all thanks for your help :) .. yes thats one of my main problems that it has to be a sl dll.. by any chance though, do you think my problem occurs due to codec issues?

Comment: My suggestion is that open fiddler.exe and just watch going bytes. In fiddler utility there is a timeline tab shows what is long what is short.If it is a webcam ,some new webcam's on laptop's has high res. so you need to resize images very fasy:) have a look one of my previous post shows resizing using nearestneighbour on ImageTools project. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10409299/413032. Even its slow yes you need a codec or you need to support streaming media.Streaming is professional and needs special server(was winadvance srv.) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with the work referenced on CodeProject. But, with that said, if the approach is indeed using frame grabs and sending jpg files, then it will be extremely inefficient, resulting in very low frame rates as you describe. 
An application like this should rely on a highly efficient encoding mechanism, based on moving video, and not still images. This will create economies based on deltas in the source image, rather than digitizing a new frame from scratch every time.
Additionally. H.264 is not intended as a real-time transport, whereas H.263 is intended for precisely this type of application.
A simple Google search will reveal a wealth of references, including the topic here on stackoverflow - [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460453/how-do-i-encode-an-image-in-h-263-and-send-it-in-real-time-using-udp)

Good luck.